# Grouping multiple text values from Query in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

So I have a pivot table created from a Query function in Google sheets that I wish to group by its rows based on a decision rule.

the pivot table basically looks something like this (a table of classes and grades, and a header with student names):

```
            | John Dough | John Though | John Doe |... |  John A Hill
   History  |     79     |             |          |... |              |
   Chem 101 |            |             |    87    |... |              |
   Phys 101 |            |             |          |... |     77       |
   Phys 202 |            |             |          |... |              |
   Geo  101 |            |      75     |          |... |              |
       ...  |            |             |    ...   |... |              |
   Sport AT |            |             |     85   |... |              |
```

now, Let say the needed score in the final exam is 75, what I'd like to do is get this table:

```
            |       Failed                       Passed
   History  |     John Dough            | John A Hill , John Deere                          
   Chem 101 |     John E , John Tra     | John Son , John Snow                         
   Phys 101 |     John B Good , John Na | #N/A                          
   Phys 202 |     John Bon Jovi         | John Diy ,  John L , John R                   
   Geo  101 |     #N/A                  | John Lennon                
       ...  |         ...               |      ...   
   Sport AT |     John Bone             | John the revelator
```

the catch is that I'd like to wrap the existing pivot table with a formula, so it looks something like:

```
=MagicFormula[Query("Data !A1:X99","select yada yada, sum(yada), Pivot(whatever)]
```

And my question is, can it be done by wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"", "PASSED", "FAILED"; A2:A, REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((B2:E>=79)*(B2:E<>""), B1:E1&",", )),,999^99)),
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((B2:E< 79)*(B2:E<>""), B1:E1&",", )),,999^99))}), 
 ",$", )})
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D},
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "select Col1", 0)}, {"PASSED", "FAILED"; 
 REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)>=79)*(QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)<>""), QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D},
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),
 "limit 0", 1)&",", )),,999^99)), TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)< 79)*(QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D}, 
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0),
 "offset 1", 0)<>""), QUERY(QUERY({List!B5:D},
 "select sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "limit 0", 1)&",", )),,999^99))}), ",$", )}})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi Player0, First of all, thank you for your answer !. about what you wrote, the issue is, I'm looking for a wrapping solution, meaning without any direct cell reference in the formula (such as "B2:E<79"). can it be done ?

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by "wrapping solution"... `B2:E<79` can be indirected like: `INDIRECT("B2:E")<79` or like: `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,2)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A),5))<79`

Comment: My intention is, is a formula without any reference to any fixed cell. i.e, a formula that can be copied "as is" to any cell, without changing any reference in the formula itself. I hope it make it more clear now...

Comment: well, that completely depends on position of pivot table, but yes, you can use indirect with address for that

Comment: That's exactly the issue here. I want the formula to have nothing to do with the position of the pivot table. meaning, I could copy and paste it to any place within the sheet without needing to change any cell reference in the formula. In the solution you've mentioned above, you are using cell reference within the sheet itself (Such as "B2:E"  or  "B1:E1") and that's what basically I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The reason for that is first of all, the dynamic size of the pivot. (the amount of students and list of courses may vary). Using a  "E1" for example demands a prior knowledge of the amount of students, and also the position of the table. One way to tackle this issue, is to transpose the pivot table, select it's first column, and transpose it again, and by doing that you get the headers ("B1:E1") Array. But as far as the other rows, I have no clue how to do it...

Comment: I see. (I thought it was clear...) it was just an example concept. instead of **B1:E1** you can use **B1:1** and instead of **B2:E** you can use **B2:Z** or `INDIRECT("sheetname!B2:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MAX(IF(sheetname!1:1<>"", COLUMN(sheetname!1:1), )),4),1,))`

Comment: Sorry for being way too annoying, but the reference "B1:1" still refers to the cell "B2" in the sheet itself. My end goal is to have an independent reference within the formula, i.e a reference to some specific cell within the pivot table without knowing it's initial position . If I'm reading your solution right, I need to find a way to create a sub-pivot table (B2:E - the same pivot table with only grades in it), and the 1d array (B1:E1) which I know how to create. the problem with using ADDRESS function is a prior knowledge about where the formula is positioned.

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1imiMZCt0M7j-Dk-6t6TTjU4gfN0WlJ3xwKJJksRXBjE/edit?usp=sharing , As you will see, the pivot table has some awkward starting position. (on purpose).

Comment: @DoronAssis answer and your sheet updated. this way you don't even need the pivot table sheet

Comment: I have tried your latter solution, and it works fine. So thank you first of all, much appreciated, and please pardon me for being much too annoying. I have one more question (If I may of course), what's the purpose of using REGEXREPLACE function in the formula ? I've tried to follow and didn't quite get it. (I'm asking for better understanding in the future...)

Comment: after every name, there is a comma so the purpose of the REGEXREPLACE is to remove a comma after the last name in the cell. demo code would be: `=REGEXREPLACE("a, b, c,", ",$", )` - paste it in some cell and you can see that comma after `c` gets removed